# route data based on provided data

Tags: routes, apache-nifi

I have flow where InvokeHttp processor get different-different data based on time . I want to forward data to different different processor based on data attribute(or any condition). How to solve following flow by **nifi** processor

[image]

Comment: Routeonattribute processor could do this

Comment: Hi daggett Thanks for you response

Comment: hi daggett  is there any processor by witch we can send data by some interval

Comment: Any processor has schedule parameters. It's not valid to set it for listenhttp, handlehttprequest, ... But for most of processors you are free to set schedule params.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use the Route On Content or Route on Attribute to route the data based upon any specific information that you desire. They Route as long as the data is in the content or attributes. I would suggest InvokeHTTP->Route On Content/Attribute->Processor X